# PHP: Phing, Phar, and phar.readonly

Tags: php, phing, phar

I'm using the PHP build system `phing` to create a `phar` archive file.

Is there any known science that will let me automatically set the `phar.readonly` to `0` (which will allow the creation of `phar` to know) during a run of `phing`, but leave it set to `0` at all other times?

Comment: `php -dphar.readonly=0` as interpreter

Comment: @mario +1 useful, but is there a way to use that with the phing.phar?  Or a way to use it with vendor/bin/phing short of editing vendor/bin/phing?

Comment: Often also works as shebang. Might make sense to use `#!/.../bin/php -Cdphar.readonly=0` then. (If it's for distribution, I'd edit it in place. Otherwise defining a `php` or `phing` shell wrapper would be easiest.)

Answer (score 8):

`phar.readonly` can only be set in PHP.INI

Their documentation says it can be set by `ini_set()` ("phar.readonly "1" PHP_INI_ALL"), but it cannot.

`$ php -r "ini_set('phar.readonly',0);print(ini_get('phar.readonly'));"
1`

Update from http://php.net/manual/en/phar.configuration.php

> This setting can only be unset in php.ini due to security reasons. If phar.readonly is disabled in php.ini, the user may enable phar.readonly in a script or disable it later. If phar.readonly is enabled in php.ini, a script may harmlessly "re-enable" the INI variable, but may not disable it.

Comment: Disable read only phar in php.ini :
[Phar]
phar.readonly = Off

Answer (score 1):

short answer: You should set `phar.readonly` the parameter in your php.ini file from 1 to 0.

long answer: I have my PHP running on docker and for rewrite `phar.readonly`, I set an INI file in the dockerfile

```
RUN echo 'phar.readonly=0' >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-phar-readonly.ini
```

docker will read every INI file that you put in `/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/` folder and will rewrite php.ini with these parameters